# Angular spyon location.path is not working in unit testing

Tags: angularjs

Angular controller:

```
function Controller($location, someservice){
   $location.path(someservice.getPath());
}
```

Unit test:

```
describe("Controller unit testing",function(){
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$location_) {
    $location = _$location_;

    // Mock someservice
    someservicemock= {

      getPath: function () { return "/somepath";},
    };

    controller = _$controller_("Controller", { $location: $location, someservice: someservicemock});
    spyOn(someservicemock, "getPath");
  }));

it("should redirect to other path", function () {

    // Assert
    expect(someservicemock.getPath).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/somepath');
  });
```

}

In this the second expect is failing. Can someone help me resolving it?